# Parsing IMG from dynamic link

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have task about parsing img src from  dynamic link by class name. For it i'm using `simple_html_dom.php` plugin. I have array with ref codes and when for each element of the array I run `the file_get_html ()` function and get a fatal error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 199233536 bytes) in 'path'

How can I kill or add to the request queue so that after each request the process stops? I called the **break;** after executing the loop, but as a result, I got one element and not all the elements in turn

***Briefly:** I have to parse the page, find the class in the same page and get the image link*

**parsing.php**

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$all_ref_codes = ['GDJW3', 'THDP', 'PDBEF', 'BDTE']; //there is a lot of ref code in the array, more than 100-200

            if($all_ref_codes) {
                foreach ($all_ref_codes as $value) {
                    $image_url = 'https://mylink.test.com/' . $value . '/';
                    $html = file_get_html($image_url);
                    $im = $html->find('.img-class');

                    print_r($im );
                }   
            }
```

Comment: What “queue” are you talking about, there is no such thing here. Your script just makes one request, processes that, and only then the next request is made. And since the variables get overwritten in each iteration, this should not eat more memory, based on _how many_ URLs you process here. I would rather suspect that one of the result pages you are fetching there is “larger” than the others, so that parsing _that_ is what actually kills your memory.

Comment: @CBroeThanks for the answer, in which case what approach would you recommend? If I have more links each time and each time I have to increase the memory of php?

Comment: _When_ does it currently stop with this error? Does it process a couple of your URLs first and then dies, or does this happen with the first one already?

Comment: @CBroe I checked, on each iteration I was creating a new DOM for each link. Didn't help either

Comment: @CBroe After 10-12 sec  get fatal error

Comment: That doesn’t tell us much, we don’t know whether it took 10-12 seconds to fetch and parse a single one of those URLs, or if it spent one second on 10 to 12 URLs each …

Comment: @CBroe How can I check this? what function takes such parameters?

Comment: Did you get to see any of the `print_r($im );` outputs before the fatal error?

Comment: (I’m not sure right now, whether PHP shows any previous output, when it kills the script with such a fatal error. If it doesn’t, then log each processed URL to a file or something maybe, and check the content of that afterwards.)

Comment: @CBroe You are right, when I check with var_dump ($ im) my browser does not have time to display all the data on the screen. It turns out that data from some links is loaded, but one of them has a long request time and cannot read the data

Comment: @CBroe Is it possible to run functions in php one by one?

Comment: You can do a solution with a meta refresh, where the page reloads itself in your browser. Pass on an index or other parameter that tells you which URL to process next … The other alternative would be to make the HTTP request using something where you can specify a timeout (file_get_contents with stream context, or cURL.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, i solve problem with ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); and after read documentation `simple_html_dom` i changed my code and can get img src for all items

Comment: @CBroe with this function `memory_get_usage ()` I was able to debug my code